# Can I send international payments using the Google Pay app?

Tags: foreign-exchange, currency, international, foreign-currency

Can we send international payments using the Google Pay app? For example, a contact in the USA, Canada, or the UK. Can we transfer money from India to the USA or Canada or UK using Google Pay or vice versa?

Comment: Does [this](https://support.google.com/googlepay/answer/12429287) help? Looks like only US, Singapore, and India are supported for person-to-person if I read it correctly.

Comment: Thanks Stanley.  I am not sure but looks like US users using GPay app can transfer money to India but Indian Users using GPay App cannot transfer money to US users using Wise or Western Union third party payment service provider.

Comment: https://ibsintelligence.com/ibsi-news/western-union-and-wise-announce-integration-with-google-pay/